# Hide ajax innerhtml

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
function handleServerResponse() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
         }
         else {
            alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
         }
       }
```

So the above is a part of the ajax code that returns a HTML and loads it into the div name message. All I want to do is to hide the div message after 5 seconds after this. I searched a lot but with no concrete answer. Can someone please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? I find it nearly impossible to think that a couple of minutes of Googling wouldn't tell you how to do this.

Comment: Also, why not use Jquery? It's easier on the eyes.

Comment: I wanted to do with ajax and also i'm new so its a learning process for me.. Thank you

Comment: Oh ok, well good luck to you. Remember Google is your best friend.

Comment: Can you help me with the answer below and my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to kick off a `setTimeout` with an inline function to hide the `message` div.

The basic gist:

`setTimeout(function() { /* do something */}, 5000); // Timeout in milliseconds`

Combined with your code:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { 
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {      
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'block';
         setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'none';
         }, 1000 * 5 /* dismiss after 5 seconds */);
      } else { 
         alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again"); 
      } 
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i'm very new to ajax and don't have much idea about it. Trying to learn. I know it was a silly question.

Comment: But in the next ajax call that div never show up. But i want it to show up after every ajax call for 5 secs.

Comment: Ah, edited for you. Just need to set it to display:block on the server response.